# Rounded Corners lost on changePage to external Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

On JQuery Mobile 1.3.1, I'm loading an external view into the dom using `$.mobile.changePage` and I use what I believe to be the correct options to load the view as a dialog. My issue is that this view loads, everything is enhanced but I lose the rounded corners on the dialog. The buttons have the correct corners, its just the edges of the dialog. When I inspect the dialog it looks like it correctly has the ui-corners-all class on the div, but I guess it isn't being enhanced? Any ideas?

```
function OpenRestoreFromBackupDialog()
{  
    if(selectedDeviceIDArray.length == 1){
        $.mobile.changePage( "../Mobile/Device/RestoreFromBackup", {
            transition: "pop",
            role: "dialog",
            //reloadPage: true,
            data:
            {
                deviceID: selectedDeviceIDArray[0],
            }
        });
    }
}
```

which loads an external page here (MVC partial view)...

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="RestoreFromBackup" data-theme="c">
    <form id="RestoreFromBackupForm" action="../Device/RestoreFromBackup" method="post">
    <div data-role="header" data-close-btn="left" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Restore from Backup</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
       content!
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" style="padding: 10px;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="e" onclick="RestoreFromBackup();">Restore from Backup</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/42DhH/

#### HTML:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
            <h1>Index page</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" id="click-me">Click me</a>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div data-role="dialog" id="RestoreFromBackup" data-theme="c" >
        <div data-role="header" data-close-btn="left" data-theme="c">
            <h1>Restore from Backup</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <form id="RestoreFromBackupForm" action="../Device/RestoreFromBackup" method="post" class="ui-btn-corner-all">
                content!
            </form>                                    
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" style="padding: 10px;">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="e" onclick="RestoreFromBackup();">Restore from Backup</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your problem is cause because of incorrect form position. Form should be inside data-role="content" div. Basically data-role="page" should have only 5 kinds of inner elements: data-role="content", data-role="header", data-role="footer", data-role="dialog", data-role="popup"

Comment: Yes, same answer as I figured out below. The issue was originally I used a submit button in the footer, rather than calling a function to serialize the form. How would I place the form in that case?

Comment: Place a form into page content div. And add a basic button to you footer. Bind a click event to your button and programmatically submit your form.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/4290

I have the form outside of a header/content/footer. This was an issue that is fixed however.